# Standard partial differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Is there any standard equation which looks like this one,
$$
u_{t}(x,t) = \alpha \, u_{xx}(x,t) - \beta(t) \, u(x,t) + S(x,t),
$$
where $\beta(t)$ is nonlinear in time, and $\alpha$ is a constant? $S(x,t)$ is a source-term which is a Dirac delta function in $x$. Or can someone suggest me a possible solution to this equation?

Comment: Could you add more detail?  I'm not sure what you're asking

Comment: The first two terms are the diffusion or heat equation. The last term is a source term that depends both on temperature and on some arbitrary function of time. Off the top of my head, I can't think of any physical process that would be represented by this. Are you sure this is the equation you want to solve? Perhaps you could add some detail about the physics inspiring this problem. I also don't see the connection between your 1st and 2nd paragraphs.

Comment: @Sean : I've edited a little bit. I think this would convey the message clearer.

Comment: @user27118 : The first two terms indeed form the diffusion equation. The source-term is added, after editing. May I please make it clear that $t$ is time, and not temperature. 
You may think of this equation as a diffusion process with $\alpha$ the diffusion coefficient, and $\beta (t)$ as a time-dependent absorption (maybe sinusoidal or exponential, or any nonlinear in time), with a point-source.

Comment: @KyleKanos : Thanks for the suggestion. I was just wondering whether or not it resembles any standard nonlinear equation. Having a rough idea of the functional form of the solution may be difficult, but I'm just being curious about it. So that I may be able to play around with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Equations that take the form
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=D\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}+R(u)
$$
are called [*reaction-diffusion* equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reaction%E2%80%93diffusion_system). Your equation is slightly different because of the source term. Here, $R(u)$ is the reaction term that depends on the function $u$; obviously in your case
$$
R(u)=-\beta(t)u(x,t).
$$
There are some cases in which the form of $R(u)$ leads to an analytic solution, however this is not true in general and I suspect that it will not be true for a nonlinear $\beta(t)$. In place of analytic solutions, you would need a PDE solver (e.g., [finite volume](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_volume_method) or [finite element](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_element_method) methods).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments. I will look forward with the numerical solution.

Comment: Wrong conclusion! This question is a linear PDE, why do you make comparison with nonlinear PDE?

Comment: @doraemonpaul: (a) nowhere do I claim OPs PDE is linear or nonlinear (though I do say that the term $\beta(t)$ is nonlinear), (b) AFAIK, the R-D equation that is the OPs PDE *is* linear. If I am wrong on either part, please show me where and/or how.

Comment: @doraemonpaul : May I clarify here as I was the one who posted this question. I did asked for a $\beta(t)$ whose time-dependence is nonlinear.

Comment: @Kyle Kanos: At least you write the ridiculous claim $R(u)=-\beta(t)u(x,t)$

Answer (score 0):

Since for its homogeneous version, it is separable:

Let $u(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$ ,

Then $=c^2$

$X(x)T'(t)=\alpha X''(x)T(t)-\beta(t)X(x)T(t)$

$X(x)T'(t)+\beta(t)X(x)T(t)=\alpha X''(x)T(t)$

$X(x)(T'(t)+\beta(t)T(t))=\alpha X''(x)T(t)$

$\dfrac{T'(t)+\beta(t)T(t)}{\alpha T(t)}=\dfrac{X''(x)}{X(x)}$

So we can analyze it just like the common heat equation.